# Socket communication and player pro

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, .netlink, networking

I'd like to create a simple communication channel between MMA and the animation package 'Maya'. This is possible over sockets ( very simple, just sending and receiving strings). I've got this working perfectly, by writing a simple .NET dll which sends and receives strings and calling this DLL with NET link. However, player pro doesn't support NET link so I'm unable to deploy this outside MMA.

Is there any way to send and receive strings over TCP/IP sockets in a way that Player Pro would support?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I'm afraid this question is outside of my area of expertise, but I'm sure someone else here will know. Might JLink be a solution or doesn't that interact well with Pro either? BTW I'm sure many of us would appreciate it if you could come up with a nice, individualized user name.

Comment: Thanks, name changed. I think I read somewhere that J/Link didn't work with Player Pro, but if I'm wrong then that would do the job.